# how i do for implement a new algorithm on optaplanner?

Tags: drools-planner, optaplanner

For my master thesis I want to implement to optaplanner "reinforcement learning" and test my algorithm with the problems that are modeled in the examples, but I need a guide or any documentation that help me to understand the way. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

[Get the source code and built it locally.](http://www.optaplanner.org/code/sourceCode.html) Make sure you fork it on GitHub.

Make sure you understand the [scope overview](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#scopeOverview).

Then find the class `DefaultLocalSearchSolverPhase` and `LocalSearchSolverPhaseConfig`: start reading code :) For a simpler example, look at `AcceptorConfig` and `LateAcceptanceAcceptor`.

A `*Config` class is a representation of the solver config XML. It builds the actual runtime class `*` which is used during solving.